# How to find the basis functions of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

For example, if I have,

```
e = a0 + a1 x + a2 (-x + x^2) + a3(-x + x^3) + .... + an (-x + x^n)
```

how do I find and list

> `{x, (-x + x^2), ..., (-x + x^n)}`?

I tried

```
Coefficient[e, a[i], {i, 0, 10}]`
```

where, `n = 10`. It shows some error. Please help.

Comment: Basis with respect to what notion of independence?

Answer (score 1):

```
e = a0 + a1 x + a2 (-x + x^2) + a3 (-x + x^3) + an (-x + x^n); 

Cases[List @@ e, a_ b_ /; (FreeQ[a, x] && Not[FreeQ[b, x]]) :> b]
```

> {x, -x + x^2, -x + x^3, -x + x^n}

Or

```
rule = Alternatives @@ Select[Variables[e], FreeQ[#, x] &] -> 1;
Rest[List @@ e /. rule]
```

> {x, -x + x^2, -x + x^3, -x + x^n}

Comment: Since "The first argument to [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) need not have head [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)", you can use `Cases[e, a_ b_ /; (FreeQ[a, x] && Not[FreeQ[b, x]]) :> b]`

Answer (score 1):

```
coef = Table[a[i], {i, 0, 10}];
e = coef.Table[If[i >= 2, x^i - x, x^i], {i, 0, 10}];

Reap[Collect[e, coef, Sow]][[2, 1]]
(* or *)
Reap[Collect[e, Complement[Variables[e], {x}], Sow]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {1, x, -x + x^2, -x + x^3, -x + x^4, -x + x^5, -x + x^6, -x + x^7, -x + x^8, -x + x^9, -x + x^10}
> ```

Did you forget `1` when writing the desired output or shouldn't it be there?